# How do I create a HeightField in pybullet?

Tags: collision-detection, python, terrain, bullet-physics

I've been looking for documentation on PyBullet, the python implementation of Bullet, but I haven't yet found a way to implement the btHeightfieldTerrainShape collision object, which I need to make, well, terrain.

If this isn't possible, is there another way within PyBullet to turn a set of points into a collide-able object?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to load a heightfield based collision shape in PyBullet:

1. manually: by mathematically creating the height field array
2. from CSV: loading a csv with the height field information
3. from PNG: loading a height field from a PNG image

Excerpts from [heightfield.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/master/examples/pybullet/examples/heightfield.py) from the official PyBullet GitHub examples:

**Manually construction the height field array**

```
  numHeightfieldRows = 256
  numHeightfieldColumns = 256
  heightfieldData = [0]*numHeightfieldRows*numHeightfieldColumns 
  for j in range (int(numHeightfieldColumns/2)):
    for i in range (int(numHeightfieldRows/2) ):
      height = random.uniform(0,heightPerturbationRange)
      heightfieldData[2*i+2*j*numHeightfieldRows]=height
      heightfieldData[2*i+1+2*j*numHeightfieldRows]=height
      heightfieldData[2*i+(2*j+1)*numHeightfieldRows]=height
      heightfieldData[2*i+1+(2*j+1)*numHeightfieldRows]=height
      
      
  terrainShape = p.createCollisionShape(shapeType = p.GEOM_HEIGHTFIELD, meshScale=[.05,.05,1], heightfieldTextureScaling=(numHeightfieldRows-1)/2, heightfieldData=heightfieldData, numHeightfieldRows=numHeightfieldRows, numHeightfieldColumns=numHeightfieldColumns)
  terrain  = p.createMultiBody(0, terrainShape)
  p.resetBasePositionAndOrientation(terrain,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,1])
```

**Loading a CSV heightfield**

```
  terrainShape = p.createCollisionShape(shapeType = p.GEOM_HEIGHTFIELD, meshScale=[.5,.5,2.5],fileName = "heightmaps/ground0.txt", heightfieldTextureScaling=128)
  terrain  = p.createMultiBody(0, terrainShape)
  p.resetBasePositionAndOrientation(terrain,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,1])
```

**Loading a PNG heightfield and applying a PNG texture**

```
  terrainShape = p.createCollisionShape(shapeType = p.GEOM_HEIGHTFIELD, meshScale=[.1,.1,24],fileName = "heightmaps/wm_height_out.png")
  textureId = p.loadTexture("heightmaps/gimp_overlay_out.png")
  terrain  = p.createMultiBody(0, terrainShape)
  p.changeVisualShape(terrain, -1, textureUniqueId = textureId)
```

Side note: If you are interested in game development, [Panda3D](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/index) might facilitate the process for you: it's a 3D engine that can build upon PyBullet.